# C programming return value odd

Tags: c

I tried to search this everywhere, but it's kind of difficult to word, it's most likely a simple fix. Basically when I go through my program that is supposed to compute the average rainfall for a year, it comes out with a very large number, however, I thought it may have been just that I was doing the arithmetic wrong or had a syntax error of some sort, but that was not the case, when I checked the value that the function returned it was the proper value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getData(float *, float *);

int main()
{
    char state[2], city[81];
    float rainFall[12], outputAverage, *pAverage;

    printf("Name Here\n");
    printf("Please enter the state using a two letter abreviation: ");
    gets(state);
    printf("Please enter the city : ");
    gets(city);
    pAverage = &outputAverage;
    (getData(rainFall, pAverage));
    printf("%.2f", outputAverage);


    return (0);
}

void getData(float *rainFall, float *pAverage)
{
    int i;
    float total;
    for (i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the total rainfall in inches for month %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &rainFall[i]);
        total += rainFall[i];

    }
    *pAverage = total / 12;



}
```

Comment: can you give sample input and output?

Comment: You are overflowing your character arrays. Your `state` array, for example, only has room for two characters, but a two-character string can't possibly fit in just two characters. (Pigeonhole principle. If a two-character string can fit in two characters, then a one-character string can fit in two characters as well. But the total number of two-character strings alone equals the number of strings that can fit in two characters. So how could you represent the one-character strings in two characters as well? Thus you need space for at least three characters to fit a two-character string.)

Answer (score 7):

you need to initialize total

```
float total = 0.0;
```

Comment: I knew it would be something that simple! Thanks so much, you just saved me some stress.

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialize the total to 0
2. Why you make it complicated? Why not just

   return total / 12 ?

   and called it like

   outputAverage = getData(rainfall)

Comment: I had it like that but I figured I need practice with pointers, this is basically a review for my final exam tomorrow, so I'm sorta making it more complicated on purpose to prepare.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in C programming.  You are mixing strings and numbers on the input.  You are better off reading the input into a string and then, using sscanf to parse it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have uninitialized variable `total` which is taking garbage value, thus you see a very large answer.

Answer (score 0):

changed your main.. have a look and let me know if you have understood what changes i have made?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getData(float *);

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    char state[3]={0}, city[81]={0};
    float outputAverage;

    printf("Name Here\nPlease enter the state using a two letter abreviation: ");
    scanf("%s",state);
    printf("Please enter the city : ");
    scanf("%s",city);
    getData(&outputAverage);
    printf("The Average Rainfall recorded for the year is %.2f\n", outputAverage);
    return 0;
}

void getData(float *pAverage)
{
    int i;
    float rainFall[12]={0}, total=0;
    for (i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the total rainfall in inches for month %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &rainFall[i]);
        total += rainFall[i];

    }
    *pAverage = total / 12;
}
```

However instead of using `gets` you should use `fgets` but i forgot how to counter the issue of using simultaneous `fgets` to read input from the standard input stream.

Also initialize the `total` variable as you are adding in the loop new values to existing value in that variable which would not necessarily add to zero as the premier element. so it could be any garbage value + loop values.

I understand you are practicing pointer concept so you passed the address of the array of floats to your second function but if the `rainfall` function is not useful in main, Better to restrict the same where it would be useful